# array_push() dosen't push new array into previous array and making new indexes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays which is lengths are same. Suppose array X and X

```
X = ["A","B","C"];
x = ["a","b","c"];
```

So what I wants to do push x values into X for each index where I need my new array as below.

```
0 => A
     a
1 => B
     b
2 => C
     c
```

This is what I have tried .

```
foreach($x as  $simplex){
                array_push($X,$simplex);
            }
```

But this give me something like below

```
0 => A
1 => B
2 => C
3 => a
4 => b
5 => c
```

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map)

```
$array = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
  return [$a, $b];
}, $X, $x)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving it would be

```
$X = ["A","B","C"];
$x = ["a","b","c"];

$results = [];

foreach ($X as $i => $valueX) {
  foreach ($x as $j => $valuex) {
     if($i === $j){
        $results[$i] = [$valueX, $valuex];
     }
  }
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: thanks for answering . Ill test both cases and then mark a answer. Once again thanks guys

Comment: array_map version is a bit more clean imho. Also, easier to expand to more than 2 arrays. However, neither solutions do not address the case where any of the input arrays is different in size from all others.